# Use special character in Perl Script

Tags: perl, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to execute a script to get data from a database with a Perl Script, but my query contain a special character because I get the information form `v$process` in Oracle.

I use these lines:

```
   my $dbh = DBI->connect ( "dbi:Oracle:$TNS", $USER, $PASS ) || die ($DBI::errstr . "\n");
    $dbh->do("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'");
    $dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
    $dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
    $dbh->{ora_check_sql} = 0;
    $dbh->{RowCacheSize} = 32;
    #Sessions, Datafiles
    my $wstmt = qq{ 
    select 'PROCESOS',count(*) AS 'TOTALPROCESOS' from v$process
    };
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $wstmt );
    $sth->execute();
    my $ref;
    while($ref = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    print join (",", @{$ref}), "\n";
    }
    $sth->finish();
    $dbh->disconnect if defined( $dbh );
```

But the result is

```
ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 57 in '
    select 'PROCESOS',count(*) AS "TOTALPROCESOS" from <*>v
    ') [for Statement "
    select 'PROCESOS',count(*) AS "TOTALPROCESOS" from v
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quote operators, like `qq`, interpolate variables.  `$process` looks like a variable in Perl.  If you want the literal string `$process`, use a single quote operator like `q`:

```
my $wstmt = q{ 
select 'PROCESOS',count(*) AS 'TOTALPROCESOS' from v$process
};
```